# C# Make URL valid

Tags: url, search-engine

I am writing a crawler in C#. Is there a way to make URLs valid? For example,
when crawling youtube, I get `/watch?foo=bar` and `bar.foo.google.com`. I want to get `http://www.youtube.com/watch?foo=bar` and `http://bar.foo.google.com`. How do I do so?

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask a more specific question. "Make URL valid" is terribly vague.

In the first case, you want `/watch?foo=bar` to become `http://www.youtube.com/watch?foo=bar`, correct?  Well that is simple. The former is a relative URL. To generate the latter, you simply need to take the base URL of the page you are on (`http://www.youtube.com`) and prepend it to the relative URL, to get the full, absolute URL.

In the second case, you have `bar.foo.google.com`, and want to get `http://bar.foo.google.com`, correct? Well this is also simple. You simply need to prepend the protocol part (`http://`) to the front of your domain.

- [Relative and absolute urls](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/design/relative_and_absolute_urls.php3)

Comment: Yeah, but how do I check which one to append?